# Grover diffusion operator for a 3 qubit system

Tags: quantum-algorithms, grovers-algorithm, amplitude-amplification

I want to make a three qubit system that marks the states where the last qubit is 0. I have made an oracle function but when I try to run the reflection the amplitudes are only higher than the others by around 15%. Is there something I'm missing out on the second reflection/diffusion operator, I'm kinda new to this field so don't know much. I have attached a picture of the second reflection as well as the probabilities:

Reflection:
[image]

Probabilities:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that $\mathrm{CNOT}$ gates should not be in your circuit. Here is Grover algorithm for 3 qubits:

[image: Grover algorithm - 3 qubits]

Put your Oracle instead of dashed line. The Oracle should have three inputs $q_0$, $q_1$ and $q_2$, output should be on qubit $q_3$ after $\mathrm{H}$ gate.

Comment: What is the output qubit used for? I always thought in the oracle you change the state of 3 qubits to 1 and use CZ to change the sign from + to -, and then reverse the operation.

Comment: @At2005: Yes, you are right that you read marked state on input qubits. But you have to somehow tell to Grover operator ($\mathrm{CZ}$ is part of it) that this state is the right one. The output is used for doing so. Although it can seems that the output is not connected to the Grover operator, it acually is because of entanglement between oracle and output qubit. When the oracle returns one on the output, phase of whole state defined by all qubits is reversed. This reversal is captured by Grover operator and after that the probability of this state is amplified.

Comment: So for my oracle should I just change it to have a CZ on the output qubit controlled by the state of the last qubit? I'm trying to mark 1/2 of all possible states. So, e.g. if the last qubit is 0 it'll mark, otherwise nothing

Comment: @At2005: The oracle output is not connected to Grover operator, $CZ$ gate acts on last qubit of input.

Comment: So right now for my oracle I've got an X gate applied before the last qubit. Then I'm doing CZ with that as a control and output qubit as a target, but it just doesn't seem to work, and I'm getting equal probabilities. I'm just a beginner so I don't have much experience with Oracles.

Comment: @At2005: Could you please send me picture (or QASM code) of your circuit (martin.veslo(at)seznam.cz) and brief description what the oracle does (i.e. what is a output for all input qubits combination)? I will do my best to help you.

Comment: Never mind, I got it figured out. Thanks for all your support though, it really meant a lot to a beginner, and I learnt some pretty cool stuff!